# How to report a bug of an unofficial package?

Tags: bug-reporting

I've installed a game called Slingshot Portal (package name: portal-slingshot) using Ubuntu Software Center.

The game fails to start with the following error:

```
Failed to execute command "java -jar /opt/portal-slingshot/portal_slingshot_1.2.0.jar".
Failed to execute child process "java" (No such file or directory)
```

Obviously, I don't have Java installed, and the package didn't have Java as a dependency. How do you report such cases?

I tried to run

```
ubuntu-bug portal-slingshot
```

But it exits with this message:

```
This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again.
```

Please note that I'm not asking for instructions on how to install Java, I'm trying to report a broken third-party package that is available for download via the official Ubuntu Software Center and therefore should have proper dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The error message means that the package didn't come from the main Ubuntu repos, and may have come from a PPA or a different repo. Therefore, you cannot report the bug through the standard channels. Instead, you'll need to report it to the PPA maintainer or repo maintainer.

You can run `apt-cache policy portal-slingshot` and see the repo the package came from.

Comment: I'm one step closer now, it's from https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/portal-slingshot/ubuntu/ . What's the next step?

Comment: I feared that. That basically means that the developers published their game on the Ubuntu Software Center, but there's only instructions on how to access that PPA (for you, since it's a private PPA and access is restricted). There's not even an email address available, and I couldn't find what could be the official website only. Is there any About screen in the game that has an email address or a website?